# Scala application on CF

Tags: scala, cloud-foundry, swisscomdev

I tried to launch our Scala application on the Swisscom Cloud Foundry (CF) infrastructure. To do so, the matching Heroku buildpack was used:

https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-scala

As this did not work, I tried to deploy the 'hello-scala' example using this buildpack.
My fork to be able to build the slightly outdated example:

https://github.com/AlwinEgger/hello-scala

I have to underline that I am fetching the port I have to use as env variable 'PORT'.

Unfortunately, there is not much on the log. "failed to accept connections within health check timeout" message indicates that there is no one listening...

My questions: Did anyone succeed in deploying Scala apps on CF infrastructures (@ Swisscom)?

Comment: Yes, this worked fine for me on Pivotal Web Services: https://gist.github.com/Amit-PivotalLabs/dfbc451165382ecf671f.  Not sure about Swisscom

Comment: Thank you Amit! I found out, that "localhost" may not be used as hostname on the new Diego architecture. It must be set to 0.0.0.0

Answer (score 2):

A workaround I found:

I'm not using the scala- but the java-buildback. This with the major advantage and inconvenience that the project is not any more build on the instance.

- Advantage: It speeds up the whole process considerably
- Inconvenience: A build server is needed

So what do we have to do?

An example may be found here (this is the actual application):
https://github.com/OpenOlitor/openolitor-server

1. Add the [sbt-native-packager](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager) to your project
2. Execute the action 'universal:packageBin' building by hand or configure your build server to do so
3. Change the buildpack in the *manifest.yml* and add some parameters, if necessary. Configure the path of the artifact to deploy.
4. Run cf push or let the build server do so.